# Are variable scopes different for strings and lists? Lists can be changed in a funtion without specifying a global variable, strings can not

Tags: python, string, list, scope

If I change a string in a function, the change does not persist outside the function

```
def f():  
    s="Me too."

    print( s )

s="I love Geeksforgeeks" 
f() 
print(s)

>Me too. 
>I love Geeksforgeeks
```

But if I do it to a list, the change does persist

```
s=[]
def f():  
    s.append("Me too.")

    print( s )

s.append("I love Geeksforgeeks" )
f() 
print(s)

>['I love Geeksforgeeks', 'Me too.']
>['I love Geeksforgeeks', 'Me too.']
```

Are variable scopes different for different types of variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the list globally, never overriding that definition.

You define the string inside the function, so it is invisible in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

These cases are not equivalent: in the first case you're declaring `s` and assigning a value to it inside the function-scope (which "hides" the `s` from the global scope) while in the second case you declare `s` before the function, inside the function you don't declare it again (which would "override" it inside the function scope) but rather start using it by calling `.append` on it, so instead of creating a local variable `s` which points to a new list - you're using `s` from the global scope.